# Moved Joomla 1.7 Site to New Server. Admin works fine. No pages display

Tags: joomla, migration

I've just moved a Joomla 1.7 site to a new server.

Administration back-end works fine. Configuration.php seems fine. Get "The requested document was not found on this server." for every page other than Home.

Must be talking to the database OK or I'd get an error. Could this be a problem with the PHP?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Did you clear joomla cache ?
- Disable page and/or module caching.
- Disable any plugin that optimizes "loading speed".
- Try removing SEF URLs (Joomla! and any 3rd party extension).
- If you are using a custom .htacess, then use an unmodified joomla one.
- Disable some system plugins.
- Disable modules in the homepage.
- Have you tried using another template (site) ?

Comment: I managed to get the flat pages working, but Sigplus plugin no longer worked. Wouldn't uninstall. Joomla was unable to modify files on the server. Eventually blocked me with a XCache (?) popup that none of my passwords worked with. Tried fresh Joomla install. Wouldn't install plugins (couldn't create/write to directories).

Answer (score 1):

You have Seach Engine Friendly URLs enabled in /administrator/ area's global configuration settings. You have probably enabled the option to use the mod_rewrite function which removes the /index.php/ portion of the urls.

It is a requirement of this mode that you have the .htaccess file in place in the root of your site. You probably had this correctly configured on your development server but perhaps forgot to move the file across when you went live. Some FTP programs hide dot files (files starting with a leading dot in the filename) so depending upon how you transferred the files (I'm guessing manually with FTP rather than Akeeba backup or similar) the file may have been missed. Look through your FTP client's options/preferences for an option to show/hide hidden files.

Failing this - the file could be correctly in place - but if you were developing in a sub-folder on your development server you would have set the RewriteBase line to your /sub-folder/

```
RewriteBase /sub-folder/
```

Now you've moved to the live server this line could be incorrect. If this is the case, edit the file to Read

```
RewriteBase /
```

Chances are it is one or other of these issues - missing .htaccess file or incorrect RewriteBase. A third and nowadays somewhat more unlikely option is that your server doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled - but I think that would result in server 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using any modules that is calling database and you have not changed DB details in that module after migration. If admin panel is working fine then I think problem with some modules that are used in front-end. You can do debugging by disabling few suspected modules and check whether your site works fine or not. Else provide some more information about your site so that I can check further.

Comment: Do modules not use the global DB details? I kept them the same and the database seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have seen some people use DB details in Modules too (like mod_php for fetching data from separate DB). If this is not then please follow the checklist given by "Shaz" and suggestion given by "Dean Marshall".  I hope that is sufficient for you otherwise post some more details so that we can understand your problem further?